# Access denied for some users - Event ID 1314

Tags: 2007, authorization

I have a really strange problem, some users cannot access my site collection root site, they get a sharepoint error "Access Denied". The event gets logged as shown next in the windows event viewer:

Event ID: 1314
Category: Web Event
Event Message: An Unhandled access exception has ocurred.

And it then goes on to show the user login, the account the app pool is running under and some other information.

EDIT: Needless to say, the aforementioned users have the necessary privileges to access the site.

The only way the users can get access is granting them site collection admin permissions, which is not acceptable.

Comment: Is this a publishing site?  Is there custom code behind any of the components involved in the page?  What happens if they go to `http://site.domain.com/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx`?

Comment: It is indeed a publishing site, the users strangely have access to the URL you mentioned, including the lists/libraries there. There are no known customizations in the site. it is a very simple welcome page with a customized master page, nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that all of the assets used in the master page and the page layout are checked in and published.  This includes CSS, Images, Javascript, etc..  If there is any custom code, verify that it also does not reference unpublished assets or other lists/libraries that have restrictive security.

Comment: Thank you. It was actually the problem. The master page the site has been using was checked out by some admin months ago.